# chromium 62.0.3202.62(latest) on ubuntu 17.10 blocks flash without asking whether to run it or not

Tags: chromium, 17.10

on different sites which are not very popular i have flash content blocked and chromium browser doesn't ask whether to run it or not.

In Firefox everything works fine.

how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to chrome://settings/ (in your Address bar) -> Advanced -> Content settings -> Flash.
There you can set it to Ask first, and add blocked and allowed sites also.